# Is it possible to assign a custom icon to a custom file extension?

Tags: windows, icons, file-extension

I am trying to make my own coding language and I want to have a custom file extension for it. I need to have a custom icon, and a way to check for text editors (vscode etc.). So it can run on any computer with the custom icon and and a way to check for a text editor that it will automatically open when you open the file, included. I am willing to use any coding languages as long as you help me out with it and dont just tell me what to do.

I have tried using the whole HKEY stuff and since I am using a custom file extension that is not associated with windows it doesn't show up in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` like file extensions that are associated with windows do.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to have an icon associated with file extension `.xyz`. And your icon is resource ID #0 in Resources.dll.

These registry keys become relevant:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xyz]
@="XYZ"
```

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\XYZ\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Path\\To\\File\\With\\Resources\\Resources.dll, 0"
```

Comment: i said custom icon and custom file extension. CUSTOM. my custom file extension isnt in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT ive already checked and i have a custom icon.